# How can I combine 4 columns of data in mysql? (3 columns are always null)

Tags: mysql, csv, merge

In my university project we got a csv file with about 15k rows and its about technical support requests, each request has one column of the brand and another 4 columns for the model, so one columns for the 4 possible brand and for each brand a column which model it is. So in each row there is only one which is filled the rest is null. I want to merge all 4 columns together.

Thank you in advance, this is my first post.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tried please

Comment: `CONCAT()` Or just browse the [MySQL Manual for something that suites](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that only 1 of the models is going to be filled, then the concat is the option for you.

```
select brand, concat(model1,model2,model3,model4) MODEL from {yourtable}
```

Hope it helps!